# Force Argon2 to return the value of p with a specific length

Tags: java, hash, argon2-ffi

I am using *de.mkammerer.argon2* library (Java) to encode a string using Argon2 algorithm. I am using the advanced interface of Argon2 as I need to provide a few config params such as fixed salt and fixed hash length.

The thing I am failing to achieve is getting the value of p with a fixed length of 17 characters (**defaultHashLen**).
Based on the documentation the param is in bytes.(https://javadoc.io/static/de.mkammerer/argon2-jvm/2.8/de/mkammerer/argon2/Argon2Advanced.html#hashAdvanced(int,int,int,byte%5B%5D,byte%5B%5D,int,de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Version)).

The encoding is UTF-8.

Is there any way to force Argon2 to return the encoded value with a max length of 17? Is it even possible?

I tried to substring the result but changing the value of defaultHashLen (i.e 17,22 ) makes the p value completely different on each execution (not sure why).

```
import de.mkammerer.argon2.*;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Base64;

public class PasswordArgon2Jvm {

private static final int defaultSaltLen = "abcdefghijklmnopqrst".getBytes().length;
private static final byte[] saltArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrst".getBytes();
private static final int defaultHashLen = 17;
private static final int iterations = 3;
private static final int memory = 1258;
private static final int parallelism = 3;

public void hashPasswordWithCustomSalt(String pass){

    // public static Argon2Advanced createAdvanced(Argon2Factory.Argon2Types type, int defaultSaltLength, int defaultHashLength) {
    Argon2Advanced argon3 = Argon2Factory.createAdvanced(defaultSaltLen, defaultHashLen);
    byte[] password = pass.toUpperCase().getBytes();
    
    HashResult hashInBytes = argon3.hashAdvanced(iterations, memory, parallelism, password, saltArray, defaultHashLen, Argon2Version.DEFAULT_VERSION);
    String hashWithFixedSalt = hashInBytes.getEncoded();
    String lastBit = hashWithFixedSalt.substring(hashWithFixedSalt.lastIndexOf("$")+1);
    System.out.println(
      pass + " \n" +
      hashWithFixedSalt + " \n" +
      lastBit + " \n" +
      "length: " + lastBit.length() + " \n" +
      "decoded: " + Base64.getDecoder().decode(lastBit));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordArgon2Jvm pa2jvm = new PasswordArgon2Jvm();
    pa2jvm.hashPasswordWithCustomSalt("santiago2");
}
```

}

output:

santiago2

$argon2i$v=19$m=1258,t=3,p=3$ZFh2dGZIWDRYdGpsV3J0OFh4NEM$2kNm9mxm8XaWcW4KIL+G7Eo

2kNm9mxm8XaWcW4KIL+G7Eo

length: 23

decoded: [B@1a86f2f1

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. The `p` parameter is the level of parallelism you set, which is 3.

Comment: Yes, but I am not asking for the p param. Just asking how I can limit the result in characters which is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

After spending sometime looking at this I have not found a way to limit the amount of characters returned. You can only limit the number of bytes returned which does not necessarily match the number of chars after encoding.